# print warning to log if then else statement sas

Tags: if-statement, logging, sas, warnings

I am writing an if/then/else statement, where the final else is :

```
if variable2 = 'foo' then variable = 'bar' 
else variable = .
```

Can I print a custom 'warning' to the log file that has a list or array of the variable2 names where

```
variable = .
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the PUTLOG statement to write messages to the log.

```
if variable2 = 'foo' then variable = 'bar' ;
else do;
   variable = . ;
   putlog "WARNING: bad value " variable2 = ;
end ;
```

Comment: to be sure it goes to the log (rather than a fileref) is best to be explicit and use the `putlog` statement

Comment: Thanks @Allan. Old habits die hard. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the OP wanted a single message with all the relevant variable names listed. There are various ways to do that... the easiest would be a quick PROC SQL on the output data set after this step finishes:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select distinct variable2 into :bad_vals separated by ' '
    from my_data
    where variable = .
  ;
quit;

%put WARNING: Bad values of VARIABLE: &bad_vals;
```

This would be fine for relatively small data sets; for big data sets you could avoid the extra pass through the data by maintaining a list of relevant values while the initial data step is running, and just print the message once at the end of the data step.

```
data mydata;
   length bad_vals $ 10000;
   drop bad_vals;
   set in end=end;
   ...blah...
   ...else do;
     variable = .;
     bad_vals = strip(bad_vals) || ' ' || variable2;
   end;
   if end then do;
     putlog 'WARNING: Bad values of VARIABLE:' bad_vals;
   end;
run;
```

or you could use a macro var instead of the data step var `bad_vals`, etc.